# get monthly date in time series object in R as a POSIXlt

Tags: r

I have a time series object with the following dates:

```
my_data = rnorm(155)
my_data_ts <- ts(my_data, start = c(2002, 10), frequency = 12)
```

How do I get the date as a POSIXlt object, and the values?

my_data_date = STHGTOCONVERTTOPOSIXLT(my_data)???
my_data_values = STHGTOGETVALUES(my_data)???

Answer (score 0):

To get the first day of the month, you can use:

```
as.POSIXlt( paste0(floor(time(my_data_ts)),'-', round(12*(time(my_data_ts)-floor(time(my_data_ts))))+1,'-01'),  tz="UTC")
```

For the values, just use :

```
as.vector(my_data_ts)
```